# How to play video by batch file?

Tags: flash, batch-file

I'm trying to open a .swf file with a batch file.  Here's my code:

```
@echo off
start "SwiffPlayer" "C:\15.swf"
start "winamp" "C:\15.mp3"
exit
```

It opens one file in Swiffplayer and another in Winamp. 
When I run my batch file, the .mp3 file starts playing but Swiffplayer waits for me to click play manually. I want to play the .swf file automatically every time I open the batch file  .I don't want to click play every time.
Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to how the program Swiffplayer works, it does not play files that are opened. Maybe you can find a commandline argument for it?

Comment: no i am not familiar with the program in question, cant you use the adobe standalone player? http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/17/flashplayer_17_sa.exe

Comment: well, if you associate that program with swf files - will it open and play? Right click .swf file -> open with -> find the program i linked -> check "always use this program". And then double click the swf

Comment: No.both swiffplayer and adobe stand alone player both wait for me to click play.no player start playing automatically.

Comment: maybe your swf-file has a stop command on the first frame. I have standalone flash player 11, and if i run the swf linked under, it plays automatically: http://www.leconcombre.com/dl/mov1/mammyblue2.swf.zip

Comment: yes Zedd mammybue2.swf run automatically in my swiffplayer also.

Comment: its mean my swf file has a stop command on the first frame. is there any way to overcome it. or remove it.

Comment: well thats a long discussion that wont fit in a comment. Im guessing you dont have access to the original .fla? What is in this swf? Is it a movie or is it an animation done in flash? You could decompile it and work with it in Flash Professional, but then you could also add the mp3 file to the same file and skip the ugly batch file. Or you could create a flash project, add (and play) the swf, and add and play the mp3. But you need some AS3 knowledge

Comment: yes I don't have .fla file..swf file contain animation done in flash.